# Showing wrong time in android device

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert, My server time to according to users android device.
My server time zone is CEST, Which i got from this command

```
   date +%Z
```

here is my code is to convert

```
String on = "2015-06-26 13:55:28";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CEST"));
Date timestamp = null;
try {
    timestamp = df.parse(on);
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    System.out.println(df.format(timestamp));
    on=df.format(timestamp).toString();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But its showing

```
      2015-06-26 19:25:28
```

While in my emulator time is 2015-06-26 17:25:28

Its helpful if i got time like 2 minute ago or like that.

Comment: What does TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName() give you ?

Comment: It's giving me this local time zone﹕ India Standard Time

Comment: Your output looks like your TimeZone actually is GMT for whatever reason. What do you get if you explicitly set `df.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST") )`  instead of `df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());` ?

Comment: I cant do that. I want according according to users device time zone.

Comment: You can't do this for **debugging** reasons ? I'm afraid then I can't help you...

Comment: Then how most of the people doing this in their application?